# С++ - gets_s() и указатели на символьный массив

Tags: c++

Недавно начал изучать C++ по книге Шилдта "С++ базовый курс" и изучая указатели и их взаимодействие с символьными массивами , столкнулся с дикой проблемой. То ли код в книге устарел , то ли VS 2012 подводит но у меня полные разногласия между gets() и любыми символьными массивами а еще большая проблема это полный отказ gets_s() (Которая работает с символьными массивами и является верной функцией) считывать данные в указатель символьного массива. По Шилдту код корректен,заголовочные файлы указаны все что нужно. В чем может быть проблема? В общем вся суть проблемы в том что  gets() вовсе не работает и что gets_s() не выполняет все нужные функции. Ниже код из книги Шилдта под копирку.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
char s[80];
int i=0;
char *p;
do {
    p = s;
    cout << "Введите строчку: ";
    gets(p);
    while(*p) { cout << (int) *p++ << ' '; i++;}
    cout << '\n';
}while(strcmp(s,"end"));
}
```

Comment: Всегда используйте [fgets](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?fgets+3) вместо gets.

Comment: Ну почему ж вы все учитесь по самой плохой книге?

Comment: @Fania Что означает, что gets не работает?

Comment: @Fania Кстати сказать, я очень сомневаюсь, что это код из книги Шилдта "под копирку".:)  По крайней мере вряд ли в исходном коде присутствуют два заголовка <stdio.h> и <cstdio>:)

Comment: @avp благодарю за совет :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте следующую аналогичную программу

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    std::setlocale( LC_ALL,"Russian" );

    const size_t N = 80;
    char s[N];

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Введите строчку: ";

        if ( !std::fgets( s, N, stdin ) ) break;

        char *p = s;

        while ( *p ) std::cout << static_cast<int>( *p++ ) << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } while ( std::strncmp( s, "end", 3 ) != 0 );        
}
```

Если ввести

```
Привет, Fania
end
```

то вывод программы будет выглядеть следующим образом

```
Введите строчку: Привет, Fania
-48 -97 -47 -128 -48 -72 -48 -78 -48 -75 -47 -126 44 32 70 97 110 105 97 10 
Введите строчку: end
101 110 100 10
```

Функция `gets` уже не поддерживается стандартом C, так как она небезопасная. Что касается функции `gets_s` , то перед включением файла `<stdio.h>` необходимо объявить константу

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
```

Тем не менее в C++ это может не сработать.

Поэтому в выше приведенной программе я заменил вызов `gets_s` на вызов `fgets`. Разница между функциями состоит в том, что последняя также считывает символ новой строки, генерируемый нажатием клавиши Enter. Поэтому в условии цикла я использую сравнение следующего вида

```
std::strncmp( s, "end", 3 ) != 0
```

чтобы исключить из сравнения строк этот символ новой строки (как видно из вывода программы, его код равен 10), присутствующей в переменной `s`.

Наверное далее в книге вы познакомитесь с функциями ввода для строк, имеющимся в языке C++, как, например, `get` или `getline`, которые следует использовать вместо функций C.

Comment: Благодарю за содержательную справку :)